# Image Uploading by using PHPhoto Libary and alamofire in swift

Tags: swift, alamofire

```
var imageAssets = [PHAsset]()
```

I am trying to upload image using Alamofire multipart.After picking image from library, i am storing it in "imageAssets". and uploading the image . In following code, two functions are there .

`func multiImageUpload(userId: Int)`  and  `func changeProfilePicAction()`
changeProfileAction function is for selecting image from gallery and multiImageUpload function is to upload these image to server.

`multipartFormData.append(image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2)!, withName: "fileset",fileName: "file\(i).jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")`.

When i am executing above code, the image is loading but with name like - "file.jpg", "file1.jpg", "file2.jpg", "file3.jpg" . But i want to send the properImage name to the server . How to do this ?

```
private  func multiImageUpload(userId: Int) {

    print(userId)

let url = myUrl

let headers: HTTPHeaders = headers

Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
      multipartFormData.append("\(userId)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "UserId" as String)
    for i in 1...self.imageAssets.count-1{
        PHImageManager.default().requestImage(for: self.imageAssets[i], targetSize: CGSize.zero, contentMode: .default, options: nil, resultHandler: { (image, info) in
            print(image!)
            print( self.selectedProfilePic.image!)
            if image! == self.selectedProfilePic.image!{

                print("exclude  \(String(describing: image))")
                print("exclude  i = \(i)")
            }
            else{

                multipartFormData.append(image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2)!, withName: "fileset",fileName: "file\(i).jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
                print("i = \(i)")

            }

        })
    }

}, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: url, method: .post, headers: headers) { (result) in
    switch result{
    case .success(let upload, _, _):
        upload.responseJSON { response in
            print(response)
            print("Succesfully uploaded")

            if let err = response.error{
                print(err.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
        }
    case .failure(let error):
        print("Error in upload: \(error.localizedDescription)")

    }
}
}
```

//  profile image selection

```
 func changeProfilePicAction(){

    let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    if (status == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized) {


        let actionSheet = UIAlertController.init(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in

            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera){
                let picker = UIImagePickerController()
                picker.sourceType = .camera
                picker.allowsEditing = true
                picker.delegate = self
                self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else{

            }
        }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
            self.vc = BSImagePickerViewController()
            self.bs_presentImagePickerController(self.vc!, animated: true,
                                            select: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
            }, deselect: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in

            }, cancel: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in

            }, finish: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
                self.imageAssets = assets
                self.multipleImageView.isHidden = false
                self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.multipleImageView)
                self.setSelectedProfileImages(index: 0)
                self.multipleProfilePicCV.reloadData()
                //self.tableView.reloadData()
            }, completion: nil)
        }))

        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)


    } else if (status == PHAuthorizationStatus.denied) {


        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: Common.sharedInstance().TITLE_ALERT, message: "Kismet would like to access your photo library, To display your profile picture to other Kismet users.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default,handler: nil))

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Setting", style: .default, handler: { (alertAction) in
            if let appSettings = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) {
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(appSettings, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                } else {
                }
            }
        }))

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    else {

        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (newStatus) in

            if (newStatus == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
                let picker = UIImagePickerController()
                picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                picker.allowsEditing = true
                picker.delegate = self
                self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: Common.sharedInstance().TITLE_ALERT, message: "Kismet would like to access your photo library, To display your profile picture to other Kismet users.", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default,handler: nil))

                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Setting", style: .default, handler: { (alertAction) in
                        if let appSettings = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) {
                            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                                UIApplication.shared.open(appSettings, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                            } else {
                            }
                        }
                    }))

                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                }

            }
        })

    }
}
```

Comment: file.jpg", "file1.jpg", "file2.jpg", "file3.jpg its displaying because you are sending the file with index in your code (`fileName: "file\(i).jpg"`) here "i" is nothing but the index of image which has stored in an image assest.

Comment: That’s right. But how to send the actual name of image ?